# Acumatica Extension on SOSitesStatusSelected

Tags: acumatica

I've been having this problem on Acumatica extension for days now and can't seem to figure out the resolution. I've added an action on the Inventory Lookup Dialog of Sales Order screen (see screenshot below), the action is task to update the QtySelected to 1 and also to update my added Field which is the Brand to "testBrand". It is an extension of the SOSitesStatusSelected table, but whenever i clicked on the action, it only updates QtySelected and not my added Field Brand.

You may refer to my code below, thank you and I appreciate all the help.

[image]

```
//DAC
  #region UsrBrand                            
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Brand", Visible = true, Enabled = true)]    
  public virtual string UsrBrand{get;set;}
  public abstract class usrBrand : IBqlField{}    
  #endregion

//BLC
public PXAction<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder> updateAttributes;  
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update Attributes")]
protected void UpdateAttributes()
{
  this.Base.sitestatus.AllowInsert= true;
  this.Base.sitestatus.AllowUpdate= true;
  foreach (SOSiteStatusSelected line in this.Base.sitestatus.Select())
  {                               

    line.QtySelected = 1;
    this.Base.sitestatus.Update(line);

    SOSiteStatusSelectedExt rowExt = this.Base.sitestatus.Cache.GetExtension<SOSiteStatusSelectedExt>(line);
    rowExt.UsrBrand = "testBrand";
    this.Base.sitestatus.Cache.Update(rowExt);        

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your extension SOSiteStatusSelectedExt is not a separate item. It's a part of the base record actually. So you don't need to update it separately.

```
line.QtySelected = 1;

SOSiteStatusSelectedExt rowExt = this.Base.sitestatus.Cache.GetExtension<SOSiteStatusSelectedExt>(line);
rowExt.UsrBrand = "testBrand";

this.Base.sitestatus.Update(line);
```

Comment: I made the same error before too and think we could throw an exception if we call update and pass an invalid object as a parameter. I don't recall what answer I got but think there was a reason why it was done like that...

Comment: tried your suggestion but still not working, is this have something to with the table being a virtual table. I also tried adding PXDefault value in the fields DAC attributes but it also does not work `[PXDefault(typeof(Search<InventoryItem.descr, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOSiteStatusSelected.inventoryID>>>>))]`